# Using an iMac 27 inch (2009) as a monitor for a mac mini with Lion

Tags: imac, display, mac-mini

My wife has iMac 27" (2009) with Snow Leopard and I want to use it as an external monitor for development on Mac mini with the latest Xcode/Lion (I don't want to upgrade the iMac to Lion to get the latest Xcode because I don't want to mess with her computer). Is it a matter of buying a Belkin mini DisplayPort-to-mini-DisplayPort cable and re-using existing keyboard and mouse? Any other issues?

Comment: Would Screen Sharing be an option as well?

Answer (score 1):

You may have already figured this out, but yes. You can buy that cable or the Apple Thunderbolt cable which is backwards compatible with Mini DisplayPort.

Good luck!